# softening colors in a matrix svg filter for images

Tags: html, css, image, svg, svg-filters

I need to use an image filter that soften red at 90%, green at 80% and blue at 70%. For example, I need to transform

```
rgb(255,255,255)
```

to

```
rgb(229,204,178)
```

(229=90%*255, 204=80%*255, 178=70%*255). So, I have defined a svg filter as follows:

```
<feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.9 0 0 0 0
        0 0.8 0 0 0
        0 0 0.7 0 0
        0 0 0 1 0"/>
```

Unfortunately, the filter doesn't work as expected since it transforms a white image in a lighter colored image than that described by color `rgb(229,204,178)`.
See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ta5zmfa4/) code and result.

Maybe I haven't well understood as a matrix filter works. How can I obtain the described effected? (red, green and blue reduced at 90%, 80% and 70%)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify sRGB as the colorspace. Add:

```
color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
```

to your filter element and everything works just fine.